# Email address Validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, email-validation

I've realized the above emailValidator function. But it's only a syntatic validation. How can I create an email address validator that checks if really that email exist?

[image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOFbu.png)

Comment: Please add a code snippet instead of posting a screenshot or image of it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine if an email-address exists, only by having a look on it. You can only check if the format is correct.

If you want to be sure, you would have to sort of ask the email-provider if the desired account exists.

You can send an email and if there is a mailserver listening AND you get no error, there should be a high probability the email exists.

What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a signup form and I want to make sure the email exist